# Ping hostname works but ssh does not for local machine

Tags: networking, macos, ssh, ping

This is an interesting one.

What is our hostname and ip ?

```
echo $hostname $(ipaddr)

TCA0080ALKVTAGB xx.xx.242.47
```

`ping` works:

```
$ping $(hostname)

PING TCA0080ALKVTAGB (xx.xxx.242.47): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from xx.xxx.242.47: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.049 ms
64 bytes from xx.xxx.242.47: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.102 ms
```

`ssh` does *not*: apparently gets lost in dns world (for same host):

```
 $ssh $(hostname)

ssh: Could not resolve hostname tca0080alkvtagb: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

Note: we have already disabled `ipv6` :

```
networksetup -setv6off Wi-Fi
```

This is on `El Capitan`.

For the curious about `ipaddr` :

```
 $type ipaddr
ipaddr is a function
ipaddr () 
{
    ifconfig -a | grep -A 6 en0 | grep "inet " | awk '{print $2}'
}
```

Oh! Let's not neglect to mention:  `ssh` with the ip addr does work:

```
ssh xx.xx.242.47
Last login: Mon Jan 16 12:24:08 2017 from xx.xx.242.47
```

**Update**

`Telnet` works fine;

```
telnet $(hostname) 22
```

Here is `ssh -vvv $(hostname) output

```
 $ssh -vvv $(hostname)

OpenSSH_6.9p1, LibreSSL 2.1.8
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/boesc**/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 56: Applying options for *
ssh: Could not resolve hostname tca0080alkvtagb: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

Comment: Can you telnet/netcat to that host on port 22? Does ssh work if you use the IP? Does ssh -vvv $(hostname) output anything additional relating to the failure?

Comment: @MaQleod  Updated OP

Comment: What is in `/Users/boesc**/.ssh/config` and `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` ?

Comment: @Jakuje  Ah yea thanks, we have proxies in `.ssh/config`  . Please make an answer and I will award. Actually .. no .. I renamed `.ssh/config` and still same behavior.  And likewise for `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`

Comment: Give it a try with `ssh -vvv -F /dev/null $(hostname)`.

Comment: @Jakuje  Same result

Comment: At this point I'd do a pcap just to see that ssh is properly asking the DNS defined in /etc/resolv.conf - it might be that it is invoking a different resolving library (though I thought it used the default resolver) and for some reason that doesn't have the proper DNS info it needs to resolve anything.

Comment: @Jakuje  Pls see the answer below: it is domain search issue : needs to include `.local` on the mac it seems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: a `macos` ism..

```
ssh $(hostname).local
```

works.  Credit to the following Q&A for "lending a hand":  https://stackoverflow.com/a/33506923/1056563

In addition the `.local` should be added to `search` from `DNS` : as mentioned here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/197884/55242

Comment: On Windows, domains for ssh require an extension. Any extension will do. Plus needed to update C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts with new host name including extension.